# How do JIT compilers work on servers?

Tags: performance, compiler-optimization, interpreter, jit

I think that it is clear that if we take the tine just to interpret a code it will be faster then to compile the same code and execute it. What I cannot understand is how jit compilers achieve better performance (in general) than interpreted languages on servers, where you have thousands of connections - is there a need the code to be re-compiled for every connection? What if there are changes? Thanks in advance for helping me to understand this better.

Comment: Interpreted code is more or less code that pretends that it's a processor running the user's code. The overhead is obviously somewhat higher than just running the user's code on the real processor. What a JIT does is figure out where the gains of compiling a part of the user's code is bigger in the long run than the overhead of doing the compilation and doing the compile then and only then.

Comment: jit compiled are slower than normally compiled and then executed, right? What I cannot understand now is the use of JIT on servers and what would happen if the code gets changed.

Answer (score 0):

Any programming language can be interpreted or compiled or even both. The performance of programs written in a programming language is affected by many factors, only one of them is whether an interpreter, a compiler or a JIT compiler is being used. Some features such as dynamic typing, dynamic dispatch and late binding are expensive and programs that use them will be slower. The language syntax itself affects performance. Interpreters can both use static optimization, dynamic optimization, offline profile-guide optimization, online profile-guided optimization or hardware specific optimizations.

However, to simplify things. We can compare interpreters and JIT compilers as follows. Interpreting a function means performing the following steps: parsing each statement, optimizing it, emitting machine code, and finally executing it. JIT compiling a function means: parsing all statements, optimizing them, emitting machine code, and finally executing them.

There are two important differences. First, interpreters parse high-level language syntax while JIT compilers parse intermediate-level language syntax. Therefore, JIT compilers perform this step much faster. Second, JIT compilers can better optimize the code by considering all statements at the same time while pure interpreters optimize one statement at a time. Therefore, the performance of the emitted binary code will be better when using JIT compilers.

As you can see, JIT compilers provide more performance opportunities compared to interpreters. This applies irrespective of whether you're on a client or server. Note that once a function is JIT compiled, it doesn't have to be JIT compiled again. Therefore, only the first user request will incur compilation overhead. All others are processed at full speed.

Comment: Actually, most interpreted languages on servers (Python, Ruby, even PHP nowadays) are compiled into bytecode on load and run in a VM thus most of the optimizations are done as well. Still, running it in a VM is slower than with JIT when run over and over again.

Comment: [You may want to check what interpreted language means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)). Python, Ruby or PHP don't have (in their reference implementation) JIT compilers and are run in a VM that interprets the bytecode. That is slower than running native code produced by JIT compiler.

Comment: @StenSoft Yes. In case of Python for example, CPython is several times slower than PyPy JIT for all but short and simple scripts. But the JIT compiler deals with much more code at the same time and therefore can better optimize it. On the other hand, CPython perf mainly depends on the limited peephole optimization.

Answer (score 0):

> I think that it is clear that if we take the time just to interpret a code it will be faster then to compile the same code and execute it.

Um, no (or at least "when")?

It takes work to convert source code into something a CPU actually understands. The are 2 main considerations:

a) When this work is done. Is the work done once ahead of time/before anything is executed so that nobody cares about it when the program is running; or is it done just before each tiny piece (e.g. statement of source code) is executed; or something else? Note that this work can be (and often is) split up and done in multiple places (e.g. "*compile and optimise to generate byte-code for VM ahead of time, then do more work to convert byte-code to something CPU understands at run-time*").

b) How well the work is done. Conversion involves optimization, some optimizations are relatively fast to do ("peep-hole"), and some optimisations are extremely expensive. For an example, imagine if one programmer created a global variable somewhere using `int foo = 4;` and then another programmer wrote `return foo * 2;` somewhere else; so during optimisation you want to search through millions of lines of code in the hope of proving that the global variable is never modified bcause maybe you can convert the `return foo *2;` into a faster `return 8;`. For another example, just trying to figure out register allocation (which variables go in which registers) in an optimal manner is a known "NP-complete" problem.

> What I cannot understand is how jit compilers achieve better performance (in general) than interpreted languages on servers, where you have thousands of connections - is there a need the code to be re-compiled for every connection

Pure interpreters give extremely bad performance. The work involved in converting code into what the CPU understands happens every time each tiny piece (each statement of source code, or each piece of byte-code if it was pre-compiled ahead of time) is executed, even if this work has been done millions of times before; and because it's working on such tiny little pieces almost all optimisations are impossible.

Pure JIT gives very bad performance. The work involved in converting code into what the CPU understands happens the first time a small piece (each linear group of statements of source code, or linear group of byte-codes if it was pre-compiled ahead of time) is executed, even if this work is only needed once; and because its working on small pieces most optimisations are impossible.

To avoid some of the problems; most modern VMs use a "hybrid interpreted and JIT" approach where (e.g.) they might interpret code the first time its executed (to avoid the expense of JIT) but switch to JIT the second time it's executed (under the assumption that if something is executed twice it's likely to be executed many times, with the hope of avoiding the "do work converting the code into what the CPU understands millions of times (if it ends up being executed millions of times)" problem). However...

"Hybrid interpreted and JIT" gives bad performance. It still can't do any expensive optimisations, still can't convert to native once before the code is executed (and avoid the "convert every time a program is started" problem), etc.

Native code compilers tend to only give you adequate performance. It's still nowhere near perfect.

The important thing to understand is that performance is relative. If one thing has bad performance (compared to a perfect optimizer) and another thing has very bad performance (compared to a perfect optimizer); then "bad" is good compared to "very bad". By changing the point of reference (e.g. comparing everything to a monkey on drugs) you could say compiled to native ahead of time gives extremely good performance (compared to a monkey on drugs), "Hybrid interpreted and JIT" gives very good performance (compared to a monkey on drugs), pure JIT gives good performance (compared to a monkey on drugs) and pure interpreted gives adequate performance (compared to a monkey on drugs).